# What's going on at f(0)?

Tags: real-analysis

Take the following simple function: $$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$$

How should one interpret $f(0)$? Is it undefined? My limited (*heh*) understanding of the delta-epsilon definition suggests that it is both continuous and differentiable, yet undefined. Huh?

Is there some sort of order of operations rule that allows the fraction to be simplified before plugging 0 in for x in the denominator? That seems arbitrary. Where does one find that rule laid out?

It seems obvious that at $x=0$ it's undefined, but it also seems that we could integrate this function.

Comment: Interesting, @abiessu. Would you elaborate?

Comment: I think the answers below expand the issue more clearly than I could in another comment...

Comment: The answer is unfortunately partly a matter of convention, so it is course-dependent. One can call it undefined. Then it is automatically not continuous, not differentiable. Or one can quietly, without explicitly saying so, fill in with the "right" value. Graphing programs often do so. People too.

Comment: A simpler example of the behavior is the function, $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [removable singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).  Your $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$, but $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=0$  It is reasonable to define a new function $g(x)=\begin {cases} f(x) & x \neq 0\\0&x=0 \end {cases}$ and note that $g(x)=x$

Comment: Would $f(x)$ be integrable from, say, -1 to 2, then? In which case, would the FTC requirement for continuity be suspended? Sorry - the fact is I'm still studying single-variable calculus.

Comment: Yes, it is integrable.  Changing the value of a function at one point does not change the integral

Comment: I'm confused: I don't think you mean that if we were to define $g(0)$ to be 10 instead of 0, the integral would not change, do you? Or is there a missing piece - perhaps you mean only in cases of a removable singularity, and/or only when the newly defined point is defined as the limit of $f(x)$ as x approaches a removable singularity.

Comment: You can define the integral in the presence of a missing point.  It becomes an improper integral, so you have to take the limit of the integral as the end of the integral approaches the missing point.  But the value will be the same as if you just define $f(0)$ to be something, anything.

Answer (score 4):

In its current state, the function is *not* defined at zero because $0/0$ is not defined. However, if we extend the definition via

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} \frac{x^2}{x} & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{array}\right.$$

then it's fairly easy to see that this is continuous and differentiable on the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$. Hence the discontinuity at zero is called *removable*, since we can remove it via adding a definition at the point of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can't speak of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$ as being either continuous or differentiable at $0$ since both of those notions require the function to be defined at $0$, which is not the case here.  What *is* defined is the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$, which equals $0$. This is because the definition of the limit at a given point does not require the function to be defined at the point.